# Looping through ArrayList in JSP

Tags: jsp

I have an ArrayList in JSP that is storing values that I have from exploding a string. These values are numbers. I can print the Arraylist out to the page just fine and I can also access individual values just fine. However, when I go to put the ArrayList in a for loop to loop through the values the page will not load(how the serer is set up).

Here's the code for what I am trying:

```
String dds = request.getParameter("dds"); 
    //"1,2,3,4,5,6,7";
String ddm = "this";
ArrayList ddr=new ArrayList();
if(dds == "null" || dds == null){
    ddr.add("99");
}else{
String[] ddq = dds.split(",");
int g = 0;
for(g=0;g<ddq.length;g++){
    ddr.add(ddq[g]);
}
}
```

This works fine and then here are the things I have tried that work (for my tests I just made the ArrayList = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8):

```
int h=0;
 for(h=0;h<ddr.size();h++){
    if(h>0){           
     out.print(","+ddr.get(h));
    }else{
     out.print(ddr.get(h));
    }
```

It also works if I just call:

```
ddr.get(0)
```

But the when I try to throw it in an if statement it does not work. Like so:

```
 int h=0;
 for(h=0;h<ddr.size();h++){
    if(ddr.get(h) == i){           
     out.print("This does not work");
    }
}
```

Also I have tried converting it to an int:

```
if(Integer.parseInt(ddr.get(h)) == i)
```

But this just leads to the page not loading again.

This may be something simple and I'm just missing it. But I'm just trying to add a feature to preexisting code I didn't make in the first place. Thanks for any help beforehand.

Comment: Where did `i` come from?

Comment: @Anthony Grist i is from a larger for loop around this code. I should have noted that, apologies.

Answer (score 0):

I got this figured out. It was a bit convoluted so I'm still open to other ideas but it gets the job done. What I did was convert both the values I was comparing i and the array value to strings and then back to integers. I'm not sure why this worked and just doing the array value did not but it seems to have done the trick.